# Internet Explorer won't download an updated ActiveX control

Tags: internet-explorer, activex

We've got an ActiveX control deployed across a large number of machines (in an intranet site). It's referenced in HTML as follows (names changed to protect the innocent):

```
<object id="foo" style="DISPLAY: none" codebase="foo.cab#version=3.0.0.0"
        height="10" width="10"
        classid="CLSID:F00F00F0-0F00-F00F-00F0-0F00F00F00F0">
</object>
```

We're about to release v3.1 of our product, so the page now reads:

```
<object id="foo" style="DISPLAY: none" codebase="foo.cab#version=3.1.0.0"
        height="10" width="10"
        classid="CLSID:F00F00F0-0F00-F00F-00F0-0F00F00F00F0">
</object>
```

However, Internet Explorer doesn't seem to want to download the newer CAB file.

What are we doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

try to replace dots to commas:

```
<object id="foo" style="DISPLAY: none" codebase="foo.cab#version=3,1,0,0"
        height="10" width="10"
        classid="CLSID:F00F00F0-0F00-F00F-00F0-0F00F00F00F0">
</object>
```